# Do injected script from Chrome Extension have access to javascript (angularjs) on the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to use Google Chrome Extension as a complementary tool for the webpage I'm developing.

I injected this `script` on the web app via Google Chrome Extension using `chrome.tabs.executeScript`.

**Injected Script**

```
<script>
    var angular = document.querySelector('body');
    var scope = angular.element(angular).scope();
    ...
</script>
```

The script is injected properly. However, I get this error `Uncaught TypeError: angular.element is not a function` when the script is called. This basically mean that the script cannot find AngularJS dependency(?).

So my question - Do injected script from Chrome Extension have access to javascript (AngularJS) on the page?

If yes, what am I doing wrong?
If no, what is a good alternative solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to reuse code from page scripts which run in an [isolated scope](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=laLudeUmXHM).

Since DOM is shared you can inject a page script by creating a script tag in a content script.

**script.js**

```
// define pageScript as a string or use xhr 
// to load it from a separate file, i. e. page-script.js
var pageScript = `
    var angular = document.querySelector('body');
    var scope = angular.element(angular).scope();
    //...`;

var scriptEl = document.createElement('script');
scriptEl.textContent = pageScript;
document.head.appendChild(scriptEl);
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({ file: 'script.js' });
});
```